# Sorting function works differently when imported rather then called in script

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7, module

Here is a function that breaks up a list and sorts it out into tuples, first object being the item, second being the amount of times it appears.

```
def top(item, default=None):
    if default is None: default = len(item)
    if type(item) is list:
        ob = {}
        for x in item:
            a = ob.get(x, 0)
            ob[x] = a+1
        return sorted(ob.items()[:default],key=lambda x: x[1])
    else: raise TypeError, "not a list"
```

If I call this function directly in the script it is written in, like this:

```
print top([i for i in "aaaabcdeee"]) 
#['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e']
```

it will print out correctly. like this:

```
[('c', 1), ('b', 1), ('d', 1), ('e', 3), ('a', 4)]
```

However, If I make a new script and import the module this function is written in, it prints out differently:

```
[('a', 4), ('c', 1), ('b', 1), ('e', 3), ('d', 1)]
```

As you can see in the above example, the objects are not sorted correctly. What can I do?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm not asking for another module, I am asking for a solution to my problem.

Comment: It works properly for me in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> return sorted(ob.items()[:default],key=lambda x: x[1])
> ```

Oops.

```
return sorted(ob.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[:default]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought I had a bug for a second. Still a mystery on why it works incorrectly when imported though. Will mark as accepted

Comment: Hashing is randomized per session.

Comment: I am more of a noob than I thought.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: source? Printing a dictionary with the keys `a` - `e` produces the same order across invocations for me.

Comment: @Tim: Which version are you using?
`$ python3 -c "print({'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'})"`
`{'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a'}`
`$ python3 -c "print({'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'})"`
`{'d', 'e', 'b', 'c', 'a'}`
`$ python3 -c "print({'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'})"`
`{'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e'}`
`$ python3 -c "print({'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'})"`
`{'d', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c'}`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: 2.7

Comment: Interesting. Why is the hash randomized in py3?

Comment: Also note that you can enable the randomization in Python 2 using the `-R` option.